# Kill a Docker Container

Tags: shell, docker, pm2

I've set up a Docker container for my node app and ran it using

```
docker run -p 4500:4500 my_node_app
```

It launched pm2 in no-daemon mode. CTRL+C and exit don't work. I've tried docker stop my_node_app in another terminal window but to no avail. 
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You will be able to see currently running docker containers using below command.

`docker ps`

Then copy the CONTAINER ID of the running container and execute the following command

`docker stop <container_id>`

Please replace  with a real value.

Comment: I've run docker ps in another terminal window and receive the message: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to run eval $(docker-machine env dev2) in the new terminal window before I could use the commands. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should update your original question with this information. In that case you'll need to turn on the docker daemon -- try running ```dockerd``` in the console.

Comment: I thought the answer below that used `docker kill` was the correct answer until I read https://superuser.com/questions/756999/whats-the-difference-between-docker-stop-and-docker-kill, so it is worth pointing out that *stop* will actually kill the container.   It just kills it by trying to be polite (at first). :-)

Comment: When you execute stop command, it stops the container gracefully. Kill command will do the same thing forcefully. So always try to use stop command.

Answer (score 4):

Do `docker container ls` to find the container name if you don't know it already, then `docker kill container_name`.

Source: [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/#examples)

Comment: how is this distinguished from `docker ps -a -q`?

Comment: There's a good response on that here @NicholasSaunders

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, pretty easy script

```
docker container kill $(docker ps | awk '/lookup_value/ {print $1}')
```

Explained

List containers in tabular structure

```
docker ps
```

Result

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
763e1a00808e        7bb2586065cd        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 months ago        Up 2 weeks          3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql_1
763e1a00999b        7bb2586065cd        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   1 months ago        Up 2 weeks          3307/tcp, 33061/tcp   mysql_2
```

Isolate your container

```
awk /mysql_1/
```

Result

```
763e1a00808e        7bb2586065cd        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 months ago        Up 2 weeks          3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql_1
```

Isolate first tab value which is the container ID

```
awk ' /mysql_1/ {print $1}'
```

Result

```
763e1a00808e
```

So in conclusion this will isolate and send the kill or stop command the container id matching the image name

Comment: You win the [useless use of grep](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#grep) award.

You can save your fork by changing this to
`docker container kill $(docker ps | awk '/image_name/ {print $1}')`

Comment: omitting the useless `grep`, it's actuall a quite useful answer.  hard to upvote it, though, because of the bad `grep` usage.

Comment: Nice to win something every now and again

Comment: or if u want to kill all running ones use 
docker kill $(docker ps -q)

Answer (score 0):

1. “Docker container ls “ to view existing containers
2. “Docker container kill container_id” to terminate forcefully or “docker container stop container_id” for graceful termination

Answer (score -1):

alternative aws

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
```

`docker ps -q` get id all containers

The command `docker kill $(docker ps -q)` uses to stop running containers.

Breaking it down:

`docker ps -q`: This part of the command is used to list the IDs of the currently running Docker containers. The -q option stands for "quiet" and is used to only display the container IDs without any additional information.

`$(docker ps -q)`: This command substitution syntax ($(...)) takes the output of docker ps -q (which is a list of container IDs) and substitutes it into the overall command.

`docker kill`: sending a signal to stop a running container. It is equivalent to running docker stop, but with a default signal of SIGKILL, which forcefully terminates the container.

Putting it all together, docker kill $(docker ps -q) stops all running Docker containers by obtaining their IDs from the output of docker ps -q and then using docker kill to send the stop signal to each identified container.

This command is useful when you want to quickly stop all running containers on your Docker host. Keep in mind that this forcefully terminates the containers, and any unsaved data or state in those containers may be lost. Use it with caution, especially in a production environment.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should killing all containers be a better solution than the ones given in the other answers?