# How do I write a script that kills a docker container?

Tags: bash, docker

I wrote a script to build and run a docker container:

```
docker build --rm -t 'mine' . && docker run -p 3000:3000 -it 'mine'
```

If I run it two times in a row, the previous one is already running so it doesn't start.  To fix this, I wrote a line to kill all docker containers:

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q) || true
docker build --rm -t 'mine' . && docker run -p 3000:3000 -it 'mine'
```

This works, but now I have multiple projects on my machine that use docker, and this kills all of them, which isn't what I want.  I only want it to kill the docker container in this project.

How can I modify this script so it only kills the docker container(s) that are started in the second line?

Comment: Have a look at [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill a Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015597/kill-a-docker-container)

Comment: @jeremysprofile I'd say it's not a dupe because the answer has this line: "Then copy the CONTAINER ID of the running container and execute the following command". I want to do this all in a script

Comment: @DanielKaplan, I'd say it is a dupe because if you scrolled down one more answer, there is an alternative that says `docker kill container_name`. In your case, it would be `docker kill mine`

Comment: @jeremysprofile in that case, I agree.  I didn't notice that

Comment: @jeremysprofile Actually, I tried that and it didn't work.  I don't say `docker kill mine`, I say `docker kill container_name` which I have to get from `docker container ls`.  Therefore, I don't think this is the same question.  I'm asking for a one-line script to do all these steps, not a manual series of steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a container name so that you can kill it by name. You'll also have to use [`--rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm) so you can restart it easily next time:

Terminal 1:

```sh
docker run -it --rm --name killMe alpine:latest /bin/sh
```

Terminal 2:

```sh
docker container ls
> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
> 0113b3fea7dd        alpine:latest       "/bin/sh"           19 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds                           killMe

docker kill killMe
# the container in my first terminal is now stopped
docker run -it --rm --name killMe alpine:latest /bin/sh
# it started again
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
docker kill $(docker container ls | tail -1 | awk '$0 ~ /mine/ {print $NF}')
```

Let's start with the `$(...)` first.  It says, list the containers, cut off the header, print the last column of any line that has `mine` in it (the name of my container tag).  The last column is the name of the container.

I take this result and pass it into `docker kill <result>`.  This probably wouldn't work if there were multiple running containers with `mine` in it, but since I can't have two running at the same time, I'm okay with this limitation.